# The number of units in the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x^4-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I am asked to find the number of units in the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x^4-1)$, where $\Bbb Z_5$ is the finite field consisting of 5 elements. I know that this ring has $5^4$ elements (which is not quite small), so I think I can't just do this using only computation. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Factor $x^4-1$ in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$ and use the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: $x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$. By the CRT, the quotient ring is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x-1)) \times (\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x+1)) \times (\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x+2))  \times (\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x+3))$ which is again isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_5$, so the answer is $4^4$, am I right?

Comment: @Troaro, exactly