# Units in $\Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z[x] / I$ where $I=(x^3+2x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-spaces

I'd like to know how to find all the units in the quotient ring $R/I$ where $I=(x^3+2x^2)$ and $R=\Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z[x]$.

I know $$R/I = \{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 + I \; / \; a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 \in R\},$$ so $R / I$ has $3^3=27$ elements.

Now, as $x^3+2x^2 = x^2(x+2)$ and $\Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z[x]$ is a PID, $I$ is not maximal. Thus, $R/I$ does **not** has $26$ units *(it would have been so easy)*. **How can I find all the units in $R/I$?**

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631439/the-number-of-units-in-the-quotient-ring-bbb-z-5x-x4-1?rq=1) from today.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The question you linked help me with knowing how many units does $R/I$ has, but I want to enumerate them. Any hint?

Comment: Direct computation? You can find zero divisors, like anything that is divided by $x^2$ or $x+2$, and throw those out as candidates for inverses, making your computations fewer.

Comment: @KeeferRowan Is there any algorithm to do that in an easy way?

Comment: Actually looking at the linked question by Dietrich, I realize you should just use CRT to get a simpler isomorphic copy of the ring. It will easier to find units there.

Comment: As an aside when you're working wiht multiplication in $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ it's often useful to use representatives that are close to zero rather than the usual $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$. So for example you'd use $\{-1,0,1\}$ rather than $\{0,1,2\}$. This keeps the calculations smaller at the expense of having to keep track of the signs and this is often much easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), the units in $R/I$ correspond bijectively to polynomials of degree at most $2$ in $R$ that are coprime with $x^3+2x^2=x^3-x^2=x^2(x-1)$. So look for polynomials $ax^2+bx+c$ that don't have $0$ or $1$ as roots, that is, you need $c\ne0$ and $a+b+c\ne0$. Choosing $a=0$ is allowed.

Comment: I know what you mean about Bézout's theorem, but I don't get your reasoning. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: Specifically, I don't get this part: "So look for polynomials $ax2+bx+c$ that don't have $0$ or $1$ as roots"

Comment: @mug_donut, If $f(x)$ is coprime with $g(x)=x^3+2x^2$, then there $f(x)u(x)+g(x)v(x)=1$ and so the $u(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$ in $R/I$. Also, every $f$ is equivalent to a quadratic mod $g$ since $g$ has degree $3$. Finally, $f$ and $g$ are coprime iff $f$ does not have a common root with $g$, since $g$ splits into linear factors.

Comment: Yes, but why you say $u(x)$ don't have $0$ or $1$ as roots?

Comment: @mug_donut, $f(0)u(0)=1$. Same for $x=1$.